# React Hooks, Reducers, Ajax, how to dispatch new state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-hooks

I don't understand yet how to play with Async request and Reducer. I don't get it.
I am using Hooks.

I have something like that:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GO':
            myFunctionThatDoesSomethingAsync(params);
            return {
                ...state,
                isChecking: true
            };
}
```

Then *myFunctionThatDoesSomethingAsync* is pretty standard, I guess?

```
const myFunctionThatDoesSomethingAsync = (params) => {
fetch('/endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: body
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            if (result.status === 'failed') {
                // this does not work, dispatch is undefined of course
                dispatch({ type: 'FAILED', result: result });
            } else {
                // this does not work, dispatch is undefined of course
                dispatch({ type: 'DONE' });
            }
        }
    );
};
```

I am sure I am missing a concept here. I am just getting started on React, Reducers, Hooks, etc.

I don't know if I need to pass the `dispatch` method somehow, but even when I am calling *myFunctionThatDoesSomethingAsync*, `dispatch` method does not exist yet.

I have read stuff related to `async` keywords, `async actions` etc. but not sure it applies, and that was not clear.

How can I do to change my *state* in this situation? (I have the same code without Reducer and that is working fine, but because I can use the `setSomething`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducers should be pure sync functions. If you need to make an async operation (call api, setTimeout, etc...), call the async function in the body of the component, and when it's done, it should dispatch the action.

For example, I've create an `asyncInc` function that dispatches after a second. The reducer handles the action when dispatched as usual, and increments the state.

```js
const reducer = (count, step = 1) => count + step;

const App = () => {
  const [count, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, 0);

  const asyncInc = React.useCallback(() => {
    setTimeout(() => dispatch(2), 1000); 
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div onClick={asyncInc}>{count}</div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Really that's it? I have just tried it works of course but I ended in the component to do:

        onSomething={() => {
                            dispatch({
                                type: 'SOMETHING',
                            });
                            myFunctionThatDoesSomethingAsync(params)
                        }}

Comment: Yep. As simple as that. The reducer should be used to transform state, not to make async calls. In redux you can dispatch actions, and do async stuff via middlewares, and then dispatched another action to the reducer. useReducer is much simpler, and doesn't have any middlewares or thunks.